# How do I insert a one column Series into a single dataframe column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I took out and copied a column from a dataframe. Easy. I modified it and now I need to put it back in but I don't know how. I have tried countless methods and none of them work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:
[code]

```
for col in ["Shares__Basic_"]:
    tmp_col = data[col]
    count = 0
    index_no = data.columns.get_loc(col)
    while 1:
        result = sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(tmp_col, autolag='AIC')
        pvalue = result[1]
        if pvalue > 0.01:
            tmp_col = tmp_col.diff()
            count = count + 1
            tmp_col = tmp_col.drop(tmp_col.index[0])
            print(col+" diffed")
        elif pvalue < 0.01:
            break
    while count > 0:
        tmp_col = pd.concat([pd.Series([float("nan")]), tmp_col])
        count = count - 1
    del data[col]
    data.insert(index_no, col, value=tmp_col)
```

[/code]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to add the column over the existing column -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]}) #DUMMY DATASET
print(df)

#>>    A  B
#>> 0  1  4
#>> 1  2  5
#>> 2  3  6

modified_column = df['A']**2

#Adding it back over the existing columns
df['A'] = modified_column
print(df)

#>>    A  B
#>> 0  1  4
#>> 1  4  5
#>> 2  9  6
```

If you want to add it as an addition column, then try this -

```
#Adding it back as a new column
df['New_A'] = modified_column
print(df)

#>>    A  B  New_A
#>> 0  1  4      1
#>> 1  2  5      4
#>> 2  3  6      9
```

---

EDIT: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` usually occurs when you have duplicate index values. You maybe corrupting the  modified_column's index accidently. Reset it by using the original dataframe's index.

```
modified_column.index = df.index
```

Comment: I tried your way initially but it gave me an error.....ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: there is no way I could help you further without you sharing the sample dataset, the code you are attempting and the complete error you are getting. Please add those to the question and Ill be happy to help you.

Comment: How do I share the dataset?

Comment: Try adding this before my code - `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: what is the size of yiour data? how many rows/columns?

Comment: its been indexed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236014/discussion-between-akshay-sehgal-and-intuition).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
s = pd.Series([5, 6])
df.insert(0, "new", s)
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Its not letting me replace the column. How would I replace the existing column and values?

Comment: I deleted the column and inserted it but it gave me this error....ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: If you update your question with an example of the dataframe and series, it will help. It can be short. See my answer for how you can very easily create a dataframe and series from scratch.